# How to dynamically implement social media share buttons?

Tags: php, html

How can I implement more than one social media share buttons which would share image and content in the same HTML page. I tried using meta tags but I need to change the content of meta tags dynamically according to each articles. JavaScript functions were used for this but that too failed.

Comment: you can use http://www.sharethis.com. I a not sure what meta tags you are talking about.

Comment: hi but my problem is i need to use different contents and related images in the same page

Comment: what do you mean by "in the same html page"??? And if meta not working than please check wether they are coming from the cache or what...

Comment: i have many articles each of which have share buttons. While clicking on the corresponding share button i want to share the related images. In the case of meta tags, it can be defined only once per page right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least Twitter Tweet Button and Facebook Like/Recommend button you have the parameters data-url and data-href to specify on each, and that should be enough to make a difference between each.
I did it here http://www.sonidosocultos.com/compilaciones
Now, for the generation of each url/href you have to know how are composed... to build an algorithm to recreate them...